# Hibernate error : Could not turn on auto-commit in an active global transaction

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jboss

I'm getting an error while deploying our application.

The environmet is :

- Jboss 7.1.3+Hibernate 4 + JPA
- OJDBC : ojdbc6.jar

The stacktrace is as below,

```
09:13:30,703 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : could not turn on auto-commit in an active global transaction
09:13:30,703 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
09:13:30,704 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."css-ear-0.5.3-SIT.ear/css-submission-0.5.3-SIT.war#css-submission-PU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."css-ear-0.5.3-SIT.ear/css-submission-0.5.3-SIT.war#css-submission-PU": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:100) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2275)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:197) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$500(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:96) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final
```

The datasource configuration in standalone.xml is,

```
<xa-datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PsaDS" pool-name="PsaDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
  <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hsot>
  </xa-datasource-property>
  <driver>oracle</driver>
  <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
  <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
  </xa-pool>
  <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>pwd</password>
  </security>
```

The driver we are using is,

```
<drivers>
  <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
  </driver></drivers>
```

Comment: When you are using JTA, you are not supposed to enable auto-commit to true and hibernate connection release mode 'ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_STATEMENT'. Please check these

Comment: @Pokuri, We haven't such configuration in the system. We haven't explicitly set the connection release mode and auto-commit (so should take default values).

Comment: As you said it takes default true for autocommit. This is not suggested in JTA. try to set hibernate.connection.autocommit as false in your application settings. In JTA commit should be handled by Transaction Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the following changes to your standalone.xml within your `<xa-datasource>` definition tags:

Add the following inside the `<xa-pool>` tag:

```
<is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
<no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
```

According to documentation:

> no-tx-separate-pools: The presence of this element indicates that two connection pools are required to isolate connections used with JTA transaction from those used without a JTA transaction. The pools are lazily constructed on first use. Its use case is for Oracle (and possibly other vendors) XA implementations that don't like using an XA connection with and without a JTA transaction.

If that doesn't make it work alone, try also to add this in your `<xa-datasource>` definition:

```
<validation>
      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
      <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
      <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
</validation>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with JBoss + Hibernate. So I don't try this adjustment. Only read some documentation. Please try separetly these adjustment:

A) Hibernate properties

There is need adjust `hibernate.properties`. I found this optional property in documentation:

> hibernate.connection.autocommit
>
> Enables autocommit for JDBC pooled connections (it is not
>   recommended).
>
> e.g. true | false

[documentation link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

B) standalone.xml

> `<share-prepared-statements>` - The purpose is to workaround
>   questionable driver behavior where the driver applies auto-commit
>   semantics to local transactions. with prepared statement cache enabled
>   whether two requests in the same transaction should return the same
>   statement (from jboss-4.0.2 - default false).

```
Connection c = dataSource.getConnection(); // auto-commit == false 
PreparedStatement ps1 = c.prepareStatement(...);    
ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();    
PreparedStatement ps2 = c.prepareStatement(...);    
ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
```

> Assuming the prepared statements are the same. For some drivers,
>   ps2.executeQuery() will automatically close rs1 so we actually need
>   two real prepared statements behind the scenes. This should only be
>   for the auto-commit semantic where re-running the query starts a new
>   transaction automatically. For drivers that follow the spec, you can
>   set it to true to share the same real prepared statement.

[documentation link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/configdatasources)